# What is "Access work or school" in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

Windows 10 has a feature "Access work or school". What is it good for and how do I use it?

I know how to get rid of it (disconnect), I know how to connect (which prevents me from controlling a bunch of useful features on my own device, such as makes my laptop to regularly reboot in the middle of my work). What I don't know is why one would ever want to connect. A quick Google check reveals that the first question people have is how to get rid of it.

I do not use Office 365.

Microsoft's own text on the corresponding Settings page boldly states that with it I "Get access to resources like email, apps, and the network", but does not mention how. Of course I already have access to email (gmail), apps (on my laptop), and network (my home wifi) without this.

[image: The Settings page where one can connect to work or school account]

Comment: Where do you see it? There are a few places where you can find this text, and for each it has a different meaning. It can be on a new install in which case it refers to single sign on with offce and domain joining, it can be VPN and I'm sure there are other places where this appears too.

Comment: @LPChip I added a picture to show where I can connect. Still my question is not how to connect or disconnect but WHAT FOR I would want to connect.

Comment: That is the function to use a private or company/school Microsoft online account directly as local Windows account. If you do so apps are able to use the Microsoft cloud services without additional authentication (e.g. Windows app store).

Answer (score -1):

An institution or company can limit the usage of certain applications to only those who have connected their account like this.

For example, imagine that you work for the company Example Corp, and you have a microsoft account with the email yourname@example.com. Now, you install Microsoft Teams and want to log in to it using that account. It can be set up such that Teams tells you cannot do this unless you connect your account. So now you have can only use the desktop version of Teams if you do this...

I don't know if that is the only reason that you would do this, but it is one (and one I experienced).